# Resulting file names as a input of a variable

Tags: c, makefile

I have many functions in different files.

eg: `OBJ_SRC=sum.c sub.c mul.c div.c remainder.c`

When I am creating a library I do like this:

```
libarithmatic.a: $(OBJ_SRC)
     gcc -c $(OBJ_SRC)  # creates sum.o sub.o.. 
     ar rcs libarithmatic.a $(OBJS) #<--- problem @OBJS
```

How to store the output of `gcc -c $(OBJ_SRC)`: `add.o sub.o mul.o..` (newly created/updated file names) into `OBJS` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is with [patsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)

```
OBJS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(OBJ-SRC))
```

Now calling gcc as part of the target to build the library is a bad idea. It misses the main point of using make at all as you are asking gcc to blindly recompile all the objects instead of having make find which have changed. The usual rule is:

```
libarithmatic.a: $(OBJS)
        ar rcs libarithmatic.a $(OBJS)
```

You can put in the [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) for compiling the .c files, but if you'd just put in

```
%.o: %.c
        gcc -c $<
```

you don't have to bother as that is implicit. Well, the [default implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) is really

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

where `CC` defaults to suitable compiler and you can override it and `CPPFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` default to empty and you can set them to whatever flags you want to use for compilation. `CPPFLAGS` is for both C and C++, `CFLAGS` is for C only, `CXXFLAGS` is for C++ only (C++ compiler is `CXX`).

---

On a side-note, I'd suggest looking at [CMake](http://cmake.org/), which supports generating build files for various platforms, IDEs and the new ultra-fast [ninja](http://martine.github.io/ninja/). The corresponding `CMakeLists.txt` would be as trivial as

```
project(arithmatic)
add_library(arithmatic sum.c sub.c mul.c div.c remainder.c)
```

and making it a shared library as trivial as adding `SHARED` keyword when you want to.

---

Note, that the `%` placeholder does not have to be at the beginning. If you want to put the objects in different directory from the sources, you can write things like

```
OBJS=$(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

(the sources have to be listed with the directory prefix in this case) or perhaps

```
OBJS=$(patsubst %.c,.objs/%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

And you can similarly use the pattern in the rules, so

```
obj/%.o: src/%.c
        mkdir -p obj
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

or

```
.objs/%.o: %.c
        mkdir -p .objs
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

You have to make sure the output directory exists as the compiler won't create it (so I include the `mkdir` in the rules) and you have to explicitly specify compiler output, because it would create it in current directory otherwise.

Comment: If I want to create `.o`s in other directory then what to do?

Comment: can I add `mv $(OBJS) ./objfiles/` line in makefile?

Comment: @SGG: `mv` won't help you much, because make needs to know which files were created to be able to do it's job. I have added examples how the patterns can add or replace directory prefix.

Comment: I already tried. but gave error: `make: *** No rule to make target \`objs/add.o', needed by \`libarith.a'`

Comment: @SGG: Most likely you have a mismatch somewhere. You can try the debug options to `make` to see what rules it tries. If you can't get it to work, it would be for a separate question then.